# Verilog FIR filter code error

Tags: verilog

I'm having issues with the signal output of my FIR signal. The signal does not filter out and there's a lot of static. Although my implementation seems to be working fine. My multiplier function has been created from the existing libraries in the quartus software and was set to signed multiplication. I really have no idea whats going on and would appreciate any help! Thank you!

Code:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module fir_filter (input sample_clock, input reset, input [15:0]     input_sample1,     output [15:0] output_sample1);

parameter N = 65; //Specify the number of taps

reg  [15:0] delayholder[N-1:0];

wire [31:0] summation[N-1:0];

wire [15:0] finsummations[N-1:0];
wire [15:0] finsummation;

integer x;
integer z;

//Specifying our coefficients
reg signed[15:0] coeffs[200:0];


always @(*)
begin

for (x=0; x<N; x=x+31)
begin

coeffs[x+0] = 0;
coeffs[x+1] = 2267;
coeffs[x+2] = 0;
coeffs[x+3] = -3030;
coeffs[x+4] = 0;
coeffs[x+5] = 4621;
coeffs[x+6] = 0;
coeffs[x+7] = -6337;
coeffs[x+8] = 0;
coeffs[x+9] = 7985;
coeffs[x+10] = 0;
coeffs[x+11] = -9536;
coeffs[x+12] = 1;
coeffs[x+13] = 10265;
coeffs[x+14] = -1;
coeffs[x+15] = 87720;
coeffs[x+16] = -1;
coeffs[x+17] = 10265;
coeffs[x+18] = 1;
coeffs[x+19] = -9536;
coeffs[x+20] = 0;
coeffs[x+21] = 7985;
coeffs[x+22] = 0;
coeffs[x+23] = -6337;
coeffs[x+24] = 0;
coeffs[x+25] = 4621;
coeffs[x+26] = 0;
coeffs[x+27] = -3030;
coeffs[x+28] = 0;
coeffs[x+29] = 2267;
coeffs[x+30] = 0;
 end
end

generate
genvar i;
for (i=0; i<N; i=i+1)
begin: mult1
    multiplier mult1(.dataa(coeffs[i]),     .datab(delayholder[i]),.result(summation[i]));
end
endgenerate

always @(posedge sample_clock or posedge reset)
begin
if(reset)
    begin
      output_sample1 = 0;
      for (z=0; z<N; z=z+1)
      begin
      delayholder[z] = 0;
      end
end

else
    begin  
      for (z=N-1; z>0; z=z-1)
      begin
      delayholder[z] = delayholder[z-1];
      end
      delayholder[0] = input_sample1;
end

     for (z=0; z<N; z=z+1)
     begin
    finsummations[z] = summation[z] >> 15;  //{summation[z][15],        summation[z][15], summation[z][15:2]}
    end

      finsummation = 0;
     for (z=0; z<N; z=z+1)
      begin
      finsummation = finsummation + finsummations[z];
      end

      output_sample1 = finsummation;
end

endmodule
```

Multiplier code:

```
`timescale 1 ps / 1 ps
module multiplier (dataa,datab,result);

input  [15:0]  dataa;
input    [15:0]  datab;
output [31:0]  result;

wire [31:0] sub_wire0;
wire [31:0] result = sub_wire0[31:0];

lpm_mult    lpm_mult_component (
            .dataa (dataa),
            .datab (datab),
            .result (sub_wire0),
            .aclr (1'b0),
            .clken (1'b1),
            .clock (1'b0),
            .sum (1'b0));
defparam
    lpm_mult_component.lpm_hint = "MAXIMIZE_SPEED=5",
    lpm_mult_component.lpm_representation = "SIGNED",
    lpm_mult_component.lpm_type = "LPM_MULT",
    lpm_mult_component.lpm_widtha = 16,
    lpm_mult_component.lpm_widthb = 16,
    lpm_mult_component.lpm_widthp = 32;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no expert on filters, but I see a couple of potential issues in the block of code used to initialize the coefficients. First, I'd suggest making this an initial block since it only really needs to happen once. Second, with a 16-bit signed value, you have a range of -32767 to +32768, but one of your coefficients is 87720, which is out of range. Since Verilog is not strongly typed like VHDL, you can do this, but the results will not be what you want. You either need to change that coefficient value or increase the bit-width of your coefficients and change your multiplier code to work with the increased width. Finally, you have a 201 coefficients specified, but your assignment logic is only going to assign values to coeffs 0 through 92. This should show up as a bunch of "X"s in your simulation (you did try this in simulation, right?). When synthesizing your design, your tool should complain, but it may just assign zero values to the initialized locations (Xilinx's Vivado does this, I'm not sure how about other tools). In any case, there is going to be a difference between what you hope to achieve and what the tool will produce.